# Java on Android: Does adding item to ConcurrentLinkedQueue copy it

Tags: java, android, queue

So I'm coming from C++ world, where the standard behavior when adding an item to a container is to copy it.

I wasn't able to find this information in the documentation for [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html), so it may be something that's fundamental to Java containers generally.

When adding an item to the queue via the `add` method, is the item copied, or is only a reference to the item copied?

I realize that objects are passed by copying the reference, but I wasn't thinking that the `add` method may create a copy before adding it to the queue, to ensure thread safety.

Also, can you provide a link to the pertinent documentation that explains how this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition: when adding object in java to the container it is passed by reference.

You can alwas create a new Object inside add method. For example:

```
list.add(new NewObject(oldObject));
```

Instead of:

```
list.add(oldObject);
```

Of course you need proper constructor to do this.

Comment: Does `list.add(oldObject.clone())` do the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, but remember that sometimes you have to cast your cloned object.
clone() returns type Object.

Comment: After some more thought, the different behavior between Java and C++ actually makes a lot of sense. STL containers default to copying the data, because the container needs to "own" the data, and control its life-cycle, i.e. be able to free it. Java, however, keeps a reference count of each object, so an object can have multiple owners without having to worry about who's going to free it. You can use a "move" constructor in C++, to avoid the copy, which transfers ownership to the new owner. Some C++ libraries, e.g. `OpenCV`, implement a reference counter, and behave similar to Java.